# Mongoose fail to set ref -Schema.Types.ObjectId- to other document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a document with mongoose according to the doc http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html
First I call parent.save and inside the callback of parent.save I use child.save.
But when I check parent.childs I can see that no child has been added.
The parent schema is Home :

```
var HomeSchema  = new Schema({


    password : String,
    draft :   { type: Boolean, default: true },
    edited :   { type: Boolean, default: false },
    guests : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Guest'}],

    _event : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Event'}

});
```

the child schema is Guest :

```
var GuestSchema = new Schema({

    _home : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Home'},
    firstname : String,
    lastname : String,
    coming : { type: String, default: 'dnk-coming' },
    phone : String,
    email : String,
    address : String,
    edited :   { type: Boolean, default: false },
    draft :  { type: Boolean, default: true }

});
```

To avoid any misunderstanding, you have to know that this two Schema are included in my user schema :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    homes:[homeSchema.HomeSchema],
    events:[eventSchema.EventSchema],
    guests:[eventSchema.guestSchema],

});
```

Now you should have all the required informations to completly understand the execution :

```
  UserModel.findById(user._id, function(err, userFound) {
    if (!err) {
      /* cleaning draft*/
      userFound.homes = that.clean(userFound.homes);
      /* setting draft */
      var HomeModel = mongoose.model("Home");
      var homeModel = new HomeModel();
      homeModel.draft = true;


      if (userFound.homes === null) {
        userFound.homes = [];
      }

      homeModel.save(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          var GuestModel = mongoose.model("Guest");
          var guestModel = new GuestModel();
          guestModel._home = homeModel._id;

          guestModel.save(function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                // @ma08 : According to the doc this line should'nt be required
                //homeModel.guests.push(guestModel._id);  so when I use this obviously the id is correctly set but when I try a populate after saving the populate do not work 
              userFound.homes.push(homeModel);
              userFound.guests.push(guestModel);
              userFound.save(function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                  successCallback();
                }
                else {
                  errorCallback();
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

This treatement doesn't result in any error. But it doesn't work as intended when I stringify the user.guests I get :

```
guests: 
   [ { coming: 'dnk-coming',
       edited: false,
       draft: true,
       _id: 53dcda201fc247c736d87a95,
       _home: 53dce0f42d5c1a013da0ca71,
       __v: 0 }]
```

wich is absolutly fine I get the _home id etc...
Then I stringify the user.homes and I get :

```
  homes: 
   [ { draft: true,
       edited: false,
       guests: [],
       _id: 53dce0f42d5c1a013da0ca71,
       __v: 0 } ]
```

According to the doc guests should be setted, but it's not <-- this is my issue. Please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I could set it manualy but according to the doc it's not suppose to work this way I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
guestModel.save(function(err) {...
```

this is wrong because you are embedding the guests in the `userSchema`.
So skip the `guestModel.save` and just `push` the `guestModel` in `userFound`

An embedded document can never a reference. You can't point to it without obtaining the parent document. So you can't do both embedding and keeping a ref to the embedded document. You should choose between either embedding or adding a ref.

My suggestion would be to design your schemas like this. Store `guests` in a separate collection. Store the ref to `guest` in `user`  and `home` schemas. If you want to store some relationship data you can store along with the ref like `[{guestId:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Guest'},field1:{type:...},field2:{...}..]` and if you just want the ref `[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Guest'}]`

Comment: userFound.guests is guests:[eventSchema.guestSchema]. the problem is around userFound.Homes[n].guests wich is guests : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Guest'}]. When I try to set the id manualy the populate doesnt work.

Comment: userFound.guests is a collection of documents(embedding).  userFound.Homes[n].guests  is not.

Comment: I edited and added a comment for you look for @ma08 in the code.

Comment: @Su4p  You are saving the guestModel and again embedding it in the userFound. What you should be doing is either just save the guest in the userSchema(embed) or save  it in a separate collection and save the reference in the userSchema. You shouldn't be doing both. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: The emebed schemas work fine and are declared the way you described.

Comment: what I want to do is to save the guest in a separate collection in the user schema. Save the home in a separate collection too and make a reference in the home to point on the guest.

Comment: When you embed stuff, you don't save the embedded documents in a separate collection. They exist within the model they are embedded. They don't have existence beyond their parent documents. So you can't save guest in separate collection and in the user schema. You will have to choose either a reference or embedding.

Comment: At first all the guests where inside homes <-- this was working fine. But when I delete a guest in a home I don't want it to be totaly deleted. Moreover my application will be able to import guests from a file this guests won't be inside a home. That's why I need a separate collection and a ref id.

Comment: that's why in the userSchema just store the ref of guest or store the ref of the guest along with the relational data of guest and user if anything exists.

Comment: I want the opposite, store the schema inside userSchema.guests and store a ref inside  userSchema.homes[n].guests[ ref ]. Are you saying it's impossible ?

Comment: So what do you want is to completely embed the guest object in userSchema.guest and store a ref inside userSchema.homes[n].guests[ref]. It is impossible as embedded documents don't have references(which can be populated)

Comment: Are you sure ? if it's true now I get why it's not working.... The mongoose doc is so poor. So If I want to be able to do the things I told you I have to duplicate the guests object inside the user.guests and inside the user.homes[n].guests ? Or else I'll do my own populate method and I won't store a ref but just an _id.

Comment: Hey you need to understand what embedding means. Embedding means that the embedding document has no existence without it's parent. As you will need guests in both the user and home, just store guest in it's own collection and add ref(_id) to user.guest and user.homes[i]].guests and if you want to store any relational data, just store along side that ref.

Comment: Now that you understand my problem. Would you say that this solution : " just store guest in it's own collection and add ref(_id) to user.guest and user.homes[i]].guests " is the best shoot ?

Comment: Ok thank you very much I just got it worked and tested.